# Make Woocommerce shop messages on the Cart page disappear after 6 seconds

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am looking for some help with an issue I have. I have no experience with coding. For my WooCommerce shop, I wanted the shop messages (cart updated and such) to disappear after 6 seconds. I got that to work perfectly with code (using Code Snippets):

```
add_action( 'wp_head', function () { ?>
<script>

 setTimeout(function() {
jQuery('.woocommerce-message, .woocommerce-error').fadeOut('slow') 
    }, 6000);
</script>
<?php } );
```

However, on the cart page, it only works 1 time after pushing update cart. How can I fix this or  just disable the above script only on this page?

Answer (score -1):

Use setInterval Method instead of timeout because it only runs once.

```
setInterval(function() {
    jQuery('.woocommerce-message, .woocommerce-error').fadeOut('slow') 
}, 6000);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Using the SetInterval, it does indeed reload every time. However, then I have another issue, and that is that the 6 seconds is not constant on the cart page. Sometimes it's barely 1 second and other times it's longer. Is there a way to force the exact time of 6000ms?

Comment: put this code in document.ready or document.load function so it will fire exact 6000ms exactly after page ready or load.

Comment: Thanks, but I have no idea how to do this. I was hoping to put some extra code in the one in the opening post to make it work.

Comment: jQuery( document ).ready(function() { 
setInterval(function() {
    jQuery('.woocommerce-message, .woocommerce-error').fadeOut('slow') 
}, 6000);
});

Comment: `add_action( 'wp_head', function () { ?>
<script>

jQuery( document ).ready(function() { setInterval(function() { jQuery('.woocommerce-message, .woocommerce-error').fadeOut('slow') }, 6000); });
 
</script>
<?php } );`     Now i have this, but still it doesnt work

Answer (score -1):

you need to step of change to make it more clear.
change in `CSS`, and add the following lines in your `.css` file:

```
.woocommerce-notices-wrapper{
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 0s ease-in-out;
     opacity: 1;
    position: absolute !important;
    right: 50px !important;
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 130px;
}
```

and also, add the following line of `JS` to your header.php or in your .js file:

```
<script>
$(function() {
setTimeout(function() { $(".woocommerce-notices-wrapper").fadeOut(1500); }, 3000)

})
</script>
```

Note:

1. if you add the second section in your JS file remove `<script>` and
   `</script>`
2. The `CSS` section is optional. And I think it makes it make the notification bar looks better.
3. You may change the number in the js to change the time.

Comment: Thanks also for this method. However, this made my update cart button and back to shop functions stop working. Also, the notification came in at a weird position. Maybe some incompatibility with some of my plugins?